# How can i vectorize this operation?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-einsum

I have to execute the below operation several thousand times and it is slowing down my code substantially:

```py
T = 50
D = 10
K = 20

x = np.random.randn(T, D)
y = np.random.randn(T, K)

result = np.zeros((K, D))

for k in range(K):
    for t in range(T):
        result[k] += y[t, k] * x[t]  # Multiply scalar element in y with row in x
```

Basically i'm trying to add up each element in column `k` of matrix `y` with the corresponding row in `x` and sum them up. I tried using `np.einsum()` to solve this:

```py
result = np.einsum("ij,ik->jk", y, x)
```

which at least gives me `result.shape == (K, D)`, but the results don't match! How can i efficiently perform this operation? Is this even possible with `np.einsum()`?

Comment: Did you try `np.matmul(np.transpose(y), x)`? Your formula equals `y^T * x` where the product is a matrix product (as in linear algebra)

Comment: also matrix multiplication: `y.T @ x`.

Comment: Unfortunately `(np.matmul(np.transpose(y), x) != result).sum()` yields `140`, so 140 of 200 elements are unequal!

Comment: The same holds true for `y.T @ x` (of course)

Comment: That's floating point errors, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those operations are the same.  You already found the (likely fastest) vectorized operation.

```
T = 50
D = 10
K = 20

x = np.random.randn(T, D)
y = np.random.randn(T, K)

result = np.zeros((K, D))

for k in range(K):
    for t in range(T):
        result[k] += y[t, k] * x[t]
           
result2 = np.einsum("ij,ik->jk", y, x)

np.allclose(result, result2)
Out[]: True
```

Likely the problem is floating-point errors in whatever method you used to determine if they were "the same."  `np.allclose()` is the solution to that. It rounds off the very small errors that occur between different methods of calculations using `float`s.

As the @QuangHoang states in the comments though, `y.T @ x` is much more readable

Comment: Oh man, i really should have used `np.allclose()`! Thanks for reminding me of that function. Also i guess figuring out that my goal was a simple matrix multiplication was too hidden in the paper i tried to implement. Thanks for the answer!